# How to display parts of ajax returned JSON in different elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to take a DRY approach to a form validation script using ajax to a php file that returns. JSON encoded reply.

```
<div id="validateName">
 <label for="name">Full Name</label>
 <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" />
 <p></p>
</div>

<div id="validateEmail">    
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input  type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@someserver.com" class="form-control"/>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Above is a sample of the form.

```
function validateInput (input, error, message) {
   this.input = input;
   this.error = error;
   this.message = message;
}
//form is ajax loaded so .on is being used
    $(document).on("click", "#contact-form-submit", function(){
      //declare variables for areas we need to add messages or warnings to
var NameValidate = new validateInput ($("#contact-form").find('#name'), $("#contact-form").find('#validateName'), $("#contact-form").find('#validateName p'));

var EmailValidate = new validateInput ($("#contact-form").find('#email'), $("#contact-form").find('#validateEmail'), $("#contact-form").find('#validateEmail p'));

var arr = [ NameValidate, EmailValidate];

function validationMessage(msg) {
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    var errorAlert = $(this.input).attr('id') + "Status";
    var errorMes = "" + $(this.input).attr('id') + "Message";
        $(this.error).addClass(msg.nameStatus);
    $(this.message).html(msg.nameMessage);  
    });
}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/postForm.ajax.php",
data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg){
    validationMessage(msg);
    },
error: function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $("#.modal-body").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
});// end ajax

//make sure the form doesn't post
return false;

}); // end submit for contact-form
```

The idea is to create an array or object for each input in the form. My main problem right now is in the validationMessage function. I do not know how to modify the msg; i.e .addClass(msg.nameStatus). The line above it was an effort to create a variable to insert after msg. but it did not work. The result would be to change the look of the input field and insert the message in the paragraph tags below the input.
The JSON returned is "nameMessage":"Name too short","emailStatus":"has-error","emailMessage":"Email address invalid".
Am I on the right track or is there a better approach (other than plugins or extra libraries) than the course I am on.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error that might be holding you back. It is near the end of your ajax call: a missing curly brace `}`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/postForm.ajax.php",
    data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        validationMessage(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $("#.modal-body").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
    }
}); // end ajax
```

So to access your message that I am guessing you are json_encoding via the php file, you will want to use something like:

```
    success: function (data) {
        validationMessage(data.msg);
    },
```

Where `msg` is the associative array key in your php to your corresponding message. You can then add it to the form using something like `$('#validateName').append('<p>' + data.msg + '</p>');`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tomanow for your response you pointed me in the right direction.
Making use of "data" instead of "msg" made all the difference. I changed the validationMessage function to use data as follows:

```
function validationMessage(data) {
    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    var errorAlert = $(this.input).attr('id') + "Status";
    var errorMes = "" + $(this.input).attr('id') + "Message";
$(this.error).addClass(data[errorAlert]);
    $(this.message).html(data[errorMes]);
    });
  }
```

This way I can feed the above function an array of all inputs in the form.
Then the success call in the ajax was modified as follows:

```
success: function(data){
validationMessage(data);
},
```

That way when multiple errors are returned they are matched to the correct input.

The missing curly brace was a result of copying and pasting into the question, good catch!